# Verifying $G*H \cong G' * H' \implies |G| = |G'|$ or $|G| = |H'|$ (All Groups Cyclic)

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, free-groups

**Hypothesis:** Let $G$, $H$, $G'$, and $H'$ be cyclic groups of orders $m$, $n$, $m'$, and $n'$ respectively.

**Goal:** Show that if $G * H$ is isomorphic to $G' * H'$ then $m = m'$ and $n=n'$ or else $m = n'$ and $n = m'$.  Here $G * H$ is meant to denote the free product of groups.

**Attempt:**

1. Suppose it's not the case that $m = n'$ and $n = m'$.  I will show that $n = n'$ and $m' = m'$ so that the desired result follows.
2. Let $x \in G * H$.
3. Then $x = g_1 h_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot g_k h_k$ uniquely s.t. $1\ne g_i  \in G$, $1 \ne h_i \in H$ and $g_1$ and $h_k$ might be the empty element.  Furthermore -- since all our groups are cyclic -- we can let $\left\langle g \right\rangle = G$ and $h = \left\langle H \right\rangle$ and observe that

   $$
   x = g^{\alpha_1} h^{\beta_1} \cdot \ldots g^{\alpha_k} h^{\beta_k}
   $$

   uniquely since each $g_i = g^{\alpha_i}$ for some $\alpha_i \in \{1, \ldots , m-1\}$ and each $h_i = h^{\beta_i}$ for some $\beta_i \in \{1, \ldots , n-1\}$.
4. Under the isomorphism $f$ between $G * H$ and $G' * H'$ there exists an analogous element $f(x) = x' \in G' * H'$.  We can use the isomorphism properties of $f$ to conclude that $x'$ has the following expression in $G' * H'$

   $$
   f(x) = f \left(g^{\alpha_1} h^{\beta_1} \cdot \ldots g^{\alpha_k} h^{\beta_k}\right)
   = f(g)^{\alpha_1} f(h)^{\beta_1} \cdot \ldots f(g)^{\alpha_k} f(h)^{\beta_k} = x'
   $$
5. From (3), we know that by the orders of the groups given in the hypothesis that each $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ must satisfy

   $$
   0 < \alpha_i < m \text{ and } 0 < \beta_i < n
   $$

   respectively.
6. Now it must be that $f(g)$ and $f(h)$ map to generators of $G'$ and $H'$ (not necessarily in this order).  This is because $f$ being an isomorphism also means $f$ is -- in particular -- a surjection.  Yet it is clear from the expression of $f(x)$ in (4) that if $f(g)$ and $f(h)$ didn't map to generators of $G'$ and $H'$, it would be impossible for $\{f(x) : x  \in  G * H\}$ to equal $G' * H'$.
7. Then

   $$
   m = |G| = \underbrace{|\{ g^k : k \in \mathbb{N}  \}|}_{\text{since $g$ generates $G$}} = \underbrace{|\{f(g)^k : k \in \mathbb{N}\}|}_{\text{since $f$ is bijective}} \underbrace{= |X| \text{ s.t. } X = G' \text{ or } X = H'}_{\text{since $f(g)$ is a generator of either $G'$ or $H'$}}
   $$

   and

   $$
   n = |H| = \underbrace{|\{ h^k : k \in \mathbb{N}  \}|}_{\text{since $h$ generates $H$}} = \underbrace{|\{f(h)^k : k \in \mathbb{N}\}|}_{\text{since $f$ is bijective}} \underbrace{= |Y| \text{ s.t. } Y = G' \text{ or } X = H'}_{\text{since $f(h)$ is a generator of either $G'$ or $H'$}}
   $$
8. If $X = H'$ and $Y = G'$, then $m = n'$ and $n = m'$ -- contradicting (1).
9. Then it must be that $X = G'$ and $Y = H'$ so that $m = m'$ and $n = n'$.  This completes the proof.

**Question:** Is my proof valid?

Comment: Can't you just look at the abelianisations of the groups, which must be isomorphic, and then use the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. The alleged duplicate that it is linked to asks HOW to prove the result. This question is asking for validation of a given proof, two separate things.

Furthermore, the manner in which answers in the linked question approach the statement diverge from the basic tools accessible to a student of introductory algebraic topology or group theory who would be asking this question. I guess you'd need more reputation to reverse this, so I figured I'd put this out there if someone with sufficient reputation agrees with me.